# issue when trying to get datatable from webservice to JSON

Tags: json, web-services

```
           function testWebservice() {


            var jsonParam = { DataID: 10 };
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/testwebservice/WebServices/abc.asmx/GetDataValues",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonParam),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                success: function(msg) {

                    console.log(msg.d);
                },
                error: function(msg2) {
                    alert("Error occured" + msg2);
                }
            });          
        }
```

this is the function to fetch data from webservice. Problem is , webservice is returning a datatable. I have to bind grid with that data. But i guess datatable format is not supported or something in json. I didnt face this issue with listitem. any suggetions??

Comment: Have you tried to remove `contentType` and see what do you get? Another thing, is it really necessary to send to your web service a JSON value? For what i see on your example, you only need a simple parameter. You can use a javascript object for that without have to use json.stringify. Last thing, can't you transform your datatable to JSON?

Comment: i tried removing contentype and i tried giving contenttype as xml as well, but no success. It reaches to webservice(debugged) but when it come out from webservice it returns error . alert("Error occured" + msg2);

Comment: Well, your ajax response is expecting for a JSON not for a datatable. Can you show the error you are receiving?

Comment: it is not going to success, rather going to error block and displaying this alert.Error occured object[object]

Answer (score 0):

lets debug it step by step.

- Have you named your datatable - if not then name it first
  DataTable dt = new DataTable("user");
- if its so, and still nothing comes, atleast check if anything at all is working, mabe try sending a string from the other side to your client side.

it should just work, try making a pastie of your code that creates/populates this table and share with us.